# Custom controller action or "CRUD" for gem method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, crud

I am using the [Socialization Gem](https://github.com/cmer/socialization) for "Liking" and "Following" objects. I am doing this via AJAX. Right now, the only likeable thing I have is a `Program`.

I was able to get it working with both a `Likes` controller with `create` and `destroy` actions, as well as a custom controller action (`like`) in the `Programs` controller.

I can post the code if needed, but I was just curious if one of these is the better method, or if both are acceptable and it just depends on my needs. (The custom method `programs#like` is less code, but it seems less Rails-y.)